# Issue getting query string parameter on redirection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a mvc core app, one page is doing a redirection to my site and I need to read the query string value, but all the time the app is returning empty when i tries to read the query strring, I'm trying different ways to read get the query string or url but in every case i got empty:

URl that is called from another app: https://myportal.com/url-redirect?name=test

And my controller:

```
[HttpGet("/url-redirect")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PortalBack([FromQuery] string name)
{
    var url = HttpContext.Request.Path.ToString(); // empty
    var displayUrl = HttpContext.Request.GetDisplayUrl(); // empty
    var queryString = HttpContext.Request.QueryString.ToString(); // empty
    
    return View();
}
```

However, if I copy and paste this https://myportal.com/url-redirect?name=test into the browser, the application can read the query string parameter.

Comment: I test with `return Redirect("/url-redirect?name=test");` and can get url and querystring correctly.Is the value of `string name` is test?

Comment: *"one page is doing a redirection to my site and I need to read the query string value"* so, this one page redirects to that particular controller and you have problem reading the query string in that controller? have you checked if the redirect having the correct query string parameter?

Comment: Yiyi, if i copy and paste the url, it works.
Bagus exactly, when the other application do the redirection, my app cannot read those values, yes, i already checked the url and query string parameter name and those are right

Comment: Try this way, `PortalBack([FromQuery(Name="name")] string name)`

Comment: TechieWords, I tried that but again, i cannot read the query string value